# Create TFS Build Template for Only Deployment without building any project

Tags: tfs, msbuild, tfsbuild

We want to create a TFS Build Template only to trigger my power shell script for deployment.
We do not want to build any project or solution as part of this process definition.

We tried editing the process template workflow and removed build related actions but still when I open the edit process template I am prompted to provide project to build in Build section.

We do not want to include our deployment script in any other build definitions as we want to decouple deployment and configure separately.

I have seen some similar questions in StakOverflow but those suggestion are create some fake projects or fake solutions to attach it. But I am looking for completely removing the build section from the build definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the workflow arguments that you don't require when editing the workflow (specifically the BuildSettings argument).

Comment: Thanks Dylan, I though I removed them, I might forgot save, I just verified and realized. That is the issue.